# How to get irregular, scalable CSS Polygons

Tags: css, polygon

so how do I get this shape [image: polygon] using CSS?

Where're two problems I ran into:

1. Using 3D transforms, with the origin set on the left center, I can use rotateY, but that gives me a non-parallel bottom to the polygon, and despite it being width:100%, won't fill the screen horizontally...
2. Using skewY, along with a parent container with hidden overflows, its possible to get the same effect, but then I encounter scaling problems when changing the resolution... Too large, and the sides become extremely tall/short, too narrow and the sides look almost the same...

Answer (score 0):

If u just want to create irregular shape SVG will be better choice.
You may try :before & :after Elements.